# What does exit status 205 mean?

Tags: linux, bash

I tried executing a file in UNIX. It showed the following error:

```
ERROR: Unable to execute 002Sanity: Permission denied 
Failed to exec()
Exit Status: 205
```

How to resolve this?

Comment: `Permission denied Failed to exec()` **Probably** your script or some subscript - `002Sanity` - called by that script is lacking the execute permission. Or your filesystem mounting has `noexec` option set.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read the documentation of the particular software giving that 205 [exit(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/exit.2.html) code. There are no universal conventions about it (except `EXIT_SUCCESS` being 0, and `EXIT_FAILURE` being 1).

FreeBSD has [sysexits.h](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=sysexits&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD%204.3-RELEASE&format=html), but 205 is not listed there.

It looks like some [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html) failed with `EACCESS` or `ENOEXEC` [errno](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/error.3.html). You might use [strace(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html) to investigate. Look also in log files (probably recently modified files under `/var/log/`).

Be sure that the script (or [executable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable) file) you are executing is indeed executable. Try to `chmod u+rx` it (see [chmod(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/chmod.1.html)).

Answer (score 1):

Exit status is only usable in context of what program exited. In this case, it might be bash (based on the tag on your question), which has a few peculiar handlings of exit status. For one, it's documented to add 128 to the signal number for commands terminated by signals. In this case, the attempt to exec() a file failed, so one might guess it's related to errno instead. Looking in /usr/include/asm-generic/errno.h shows no errors as high as 205, so at a guess it has another number added. That number could be 192 (128+64, or the two highest bits of an octet). This leaves 13, which is EACCES (permission denied), the most likely error for an exec after simply not found; and indeed, that would confirm our error message which already said "Permission denied". Most likely the file you tried to execute is not executable (make it so with chmod +x), possibly the filesystem it's on is mounted without permitting any execution (flag noexec).

Comment: The idea that 205 represents 192 + EACCES seems like speculation at best. Do you have any examples of a program that actually uses this convention?

Comment: You're right, it is speculation. Unfortunately even digging in the source for a few minutes doesn't reveal how it comes about in bash; the expected value seems to be 1 (if exit on error is enabled) or one of the EX_ macros in shell.h, which are 2, 124-127, and 256-261. Perhaps the report is from another shell? I also cannot find either error message in bash.

Comment: The ERROR: message looks like sudo's output from the sudoers plugin, but it would likely return 127. Not much to go on, as it's not clear what was attempted or what printed the exit status.